# Using TTY on Android without requiring additional hardware

Tags: applications, calls

Is there any solution to use full TTY (text to text communication over regular telephone communication) from Android?

Despite the fact that Android's default Phone app has an option for full TTY support, it doesn't seem to allow communication with a TTY number. What else is needed to communicate using TTY?

Comment: I'm not sure about the tags here. The Phone app does not seem to have a tag, nor does TTY.

Comment: Since there's no TTY tag here, could you expand this question by at least explaining what's TTY in a simple way? Is it similar to [teletypewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_device_for_the_deaf)? Also, just in case, could you also explain what are you trying to do? Perhaps we can suggest alternative solutions. (e.g. realtime messaging app)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, the link that you mentioned. Teletypewriters provided an early method of sending textual data over phone lines. Very rudimentary. Clearly inferior to texting. I need to communicate with a government agency that has no email or other form of communication that I'm able to use as a part-deaf person. Their TTY support seems the only option. However, it's a  very dated technology, so it's very hard to find up-to-date information on using it aside from the fact that Android's Phone app has a mode for it. I'm looking for a software solution to using TTY for communication.

Comment: It seems the built in TTY modes are only usable if you plug an external TTY terminal into the audio connector, according to this ehow article: http://www.ehow.com/facts_5230442_tty-mode-cell-phones_.html I wasn't able to find any software only solutions for Android either, I'm afraid this is because it's a feature that is used so rarely that nobody has created a software only solution for it (yet).